# How to show all results instead of limited result in order page wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have removed pagination conditions from my wordpress page but it is still showing limited results and i want to show all results.
This is my originial code :

```
$seller_id    = get_current_user_id();
$order_status = isset( $_GET['order_status'] ) ? sanitize_key( $_GET['order_status'] ) : 'all';
$pages = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($pages) && $pages[4]!=''){ $paged = $pages[4]; }else{ $paged = 1;}
$limit        = 10;
$offset       = ( $paged - 1 ) * $limit;

$user_orders  = dokan_get_seller_orders( $seller_id, $order_status, $limit, $offset );
```

and this is my modified code, it is still only showing 10 results :

```
$seller_id    = get_current_user_id();
$order_status = isset( $_GET['order_status'] ) ? sanitize_key( $_GET['order_status'] ) : 'all';

$user_orders  = dokan_get_seller_orders( $seller_id, $order_status);
```

Comment: Did you try setting the limit to the total number of posts?

Comment: Did you try to override `$limit = 10;` to `$limit = -1;` and `$offset = 0`?

Comment: Thanks, it is done now.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using :

```
$order_count = dokan_get_seller_orders_number( $seller_id, $order_status );      
$limit        = $order_count;
$offset       = 0;

$user_orders  = dokan_get_seller_orders( $seller_id, $order_status, $limit, $offset );
```